# MVC Source Files

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm researching a basic, stand-alone UI app that I want to be 'MVC compliant'.

My question is, what is the typical correlation of the three layers to source code files?

In other words: should I expect to see separate fooView, fooModel and fooController files, or are some functions (eg. Controller) typically specified declaratively and/or handled by a framework?

I realize there are a million MVC frameworks and that the answer probably varies, just looking for a general concept. Cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the server-side language that you have available and narrow down your MVC framework from there. I would stick with a framework that fits your programming style and needs. Yes, you should have three unique layers (models, views, and controllers) and they should not mix. I.e., in ASP.NET MVC projects you would find a controller, model, and view folder.